# Parse iOS SDK: How to check for BOOLean?

Tags: ios, parse-platform

What is the way one would go about getting this idea to work?

```
if ([[PFUser currentUser][@"isBool"]==YES) {

    //do something

}
```

I just tried this and it does not work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `PFUser` is basically an `NSDictionary`, and you can't store BOOL values directly in a dictionary. It is most likely casted as an `NSNumber`, and you need to call `-boolValue` to access it.

This should work:

```
if ([[[PFUser currentUser] objectForKey:@"isBool"] boolValue]) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So checking boolValue is basically checking for "true" or in Objective-C's case, YES?

Comment: -boolValue will return a boolean YES or NO. The reason I took out the `== YES` is because it ends up being redundant. But you could put it back in if you wanted to.

Comment: ... and that's because of the way C evaluates conditions. It's not Objective-C specific.